# How to display only a particular cloumn data from the table dynamically

Tags: sql

I have to display only a particular column data by passing the column name as input.

Comment: Please share some block of code and tell us where you have to display the records.

Comment: probably you should look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL))

Comment: `select particular_column from table_name`

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL. But join to sys.columns to avoid SQL Injection attacks.
sample query will be like below

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
    FROM Report.InfoColumnOrder r
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.name = r.ColumnName AND c.object_id = object_id('dbo.Info')
    WHERE u.UserId = @user
    ORDER BY r.SN
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') +
 ' FROM dbo.Info'
;
EXEC sp_executesql @qry, N'@user int', @user = @userid;
```